# Работа с БД в C++ VS

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, c++-cli, mysqlconnector

К примеру у меня есть БД которая в таблице имеет нужные мне поля. Я сделал проверку запросом на правильность логина и пароля для продолжения работы программы и дальше данные пользователя должны поступать как параметры о объект для продолжения работы с ними. Как реализовать запрос на получения определённых данных с БД для импорта их в обычные переменные ?
Конструктор класса:

```
    user(int _number, string _name, string _sname, string _tname, bool _sex, int _age, int _birth_day, int _birth_mounth, int _birth_year, string _phone_number, string _adress, int _type_of_acces);
```

То что имеется:

```
private: System::Void loginbutton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=bd";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from users where login='" + this->logintextbox->Text + "' and  pass ='" + this->passtextbox->Text + "';", conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
    try {
        conDataBase->Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (myReader->Read()) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            MessageBox::Show("Corect!");
        }
        else MessageBox::Show("Username and pass is not corect!");
    }
    catch (Exception^ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
};
```

Можете также литературу подсказать.

Comment: `System::Object^` больше смахивает на C++/CLI.

Comment: Литература: "Программирование на Microsoft ADO.NET 2.0", Дэвид Сеппа; "Microsoft ADO.NET 2.0 для профессионалов", Сахил Малик. Там примеры на C# и VB.NET, но это не играет роли.

Comment: В цикле `while` пишете что-то вроде: `number = myReader->GetInt32(0);` и т. п. Смотрите [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx).